# Java: Cannot use the "USE" keyword from MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two SQL files:

query1.sql

```
SELECT * FROM laptop_store.gpu;
```

query2.sql

```
USE laptop_store;
SELECT * FROM gpu
```

Excecuting both in MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE will display the same result :

[image: result:]

When I copy everything from two SQL code and run it in java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class NewClass {
    static String queryString1 = "SELECT * FROM laptop_store.gpu";

    static String queryString2 = "USE laptop_store;\n" +
                                 "SELECT * FROM gpu";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try{      
          Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( 
              "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/laptop_store","root","tomnisa123");          

          Statement statement = con.createStatement();   

          //Change SQL code here:
          ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString1); 

          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

          int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            while(rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++){          
                    System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

          con.close();  

       } catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println(e);
       }  
    }  
}
```

Only the first one is success

[image: success].

But the second one shows an error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM gpu' at line 2
```

Why I cannot use the "USE" keyword from MySQL?

Comment: Why do you want to? You're already using the `laptop_store` database, the `USE` line is unnecessary.

Comment: Pretty sure the Java MySQL client functions createStatement and executeQuery does not support multiple SQL statements separated by semicon.

Comment: I removed the `USE` line and it fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is that you are trying to execute two SQL statements in a single `executeQuery` call.  You can't do that.  Run the "use" in a separate `execute` calls.

But the question is why are you using the `use` statement?

- If you are using it for no particular reasons ... don't.
- If you are using it to make sure that you are using the correct database, that is unnecessary.  The database / schema to be used is specified in the connection URL.

  ```
   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/laptop_store"
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- If you are using it to dynamically *switch* between databases / schemas, it may be better to use a separate connection for each database.